# Delete Instagram Comments based on Keywords via API

Tags: comments, instagram-api

I know someone trying to censor their instagram comments.
They want certain keywords omitted from the comments when they come in, and if the comment contains those keywords, then delete that comment.

Whats the easiest way to listen for all comment streams coming in? How to implement this on existing comments that have those keywords?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Just updated, as I just realized not really any questions. Added Q.

Comment: Use Smart Moderation for this problem if you want.